# java- library to extract/compress files from/ into archives

Tags: java, compression, zip, archive, tar

I am looking for a java library that extracts files from archives/ compresses files to create archives.

Given below are my requirements--

(1) It should extract widest range/types of archives 
(2) Simple and requiring only few lines of code (unlike java's default zip class).
(3) Production -grade: without defects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache commons compress seems to be a good fit, it can deal with quite alot of different compression types and is very straight forward to use.

http://commons.apache.org/compress/index.html